# Adding a foreign key constraint without losing the current data

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, foreign-key

I have one table called `users` and another table called `teachers` (the `users` table has data in it).

I want to add a column to `teachers` with a foreign key constraint making a reference to a column named `id` in the `users` table.

How can I do that without losing the rows contained in the `users` table?

Comment: Why would you lose the rows in the users table?

Comment: I mean the teacher's table has data on it and I want to add a new column that is a foreign key to the user's table the column is not null I don't want it to be nullable when I run the query I get a foreign key constraint error.

Comment: Like Evan said, you won't lose data by adding a Foreign Key. Can you share the commands you're running and the resulting error message? That will help immensely. It sounds like you're trying to do several things in one step and getting errors. You need to add the column, populate the data, enforce not null, add foreign key. If there's a default value you can add, which is in the students table, then you may be able to do it in one statement. Trying breaking it up into multiple steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment (quote): "the teacher's table has data on it and I want to add a new column that is a foreign key to the user's table the column is not null I don't want it to be nullable when I run the query I get a foreign key constraint error"  ... seems to indicate that your situation looks a bit like this (MySQL 5.7):

```
-- both users and teachers contain data ...
create table users (
  userid integer primary key
);

create table teachers(
  teacherid integer primary key
);

insert into users values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);

insert into teachers values (10),(11),(12),(13),(14);
```

Adding a column and a NOT NULL constraint to the TEACHERS table works ...
MySQL just sets the userids to 0 (!) - as they cannot be NULL
(This step should not be possible e.g. a Postgresql server or Oracle would laugh in our face if we tried this.)

```
alter table teachers 
add userid integer not null;

mysql> select * from teachers;
+-----------+--------+
| teacherid | userid |
+-----------+--------+
|        10 |      0 |
|        11 |      0 |
|        12 |      0 |
|        13 |      0 |
|        14 |      0 |
+-----------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

-- Do we really have a NOT NULL constraint now (userid)?  Yes.
mysql> insert into teachers values (16, NULL);
ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'userid' cannot be null
```

Now, lets add a foreign key constraint.  This fails, as all userids in TEACHERS are 0, and there is no user with userid 0 in USERS.  (I think that this is the step that is giving you grief.)

```
mysql> alter table teachers
    -> add constraint theforeignkey
    -> foreign key (userid) references users(userid);
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`#sql-554_4`, CONSTRAINT `theforeignkey` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `users` (`userid`))
```

Now - we could do something like the next couple of steps.  I DO NOT RECOMMEND THIS for real life settings as it involves using incorrect data.

MySQL allowed the teachers.userid to be 0 (which is incorrect).  If we use a valid userid instead, we can subsequently apply the foreign key constraint.  CAVEAT: the UPDATE will (most likely) use incorrect values.

```
mysql> update teachers
    -> set userid = 1 ;
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 5  Changed: 5  Warnings: 0


-- works now
mysql> alter table teachers
    -> add constraint theforeignkey
    -> foreign key (userid) references users(userid);
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Are both the NOT NULL and the FOREIGN KEY in place now? Yes.

```
mysql> insert into teachers values (16, NULL);
ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'userid' cannot be null

mysql> insert into teachers values (16, 1000);
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`teachers`, CONSTRAINT `theforeignkey` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `users` (`userid`))

mysql> insert into teachers values (16, 2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from teachers;
+-----------+--------+
| teacherid | userid |
+-----------+--------+
|        10 |      1 |
|        11 |      1 |
|        12 |      1 |
|        13 |      1 |
|        14 |      1 |
|        16 |      2 |
+-----------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

CAUTION: now you need to check (and amend if necessary) all the mappings teacherid <-> userid (in the TEACHERS table)!  You are on thin ice when running the update.  It would be better to use correct DDL code first, and then insert correct data right from the start.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you lose the rows in the users table when you add a column to it? The rows just get initialized with a null value.  After you place the foreign key constraint, future rows with that column set to non-null get checked against the table the column references.

There are three ways for you to lose rows.

- `DELETE`
- `TRUNCATE`
- `DROP TABLE`

Comment: The teacher's table has records on it and when I want to add a not null column that is also a foreign key to user's table I have got a foreign key constraint error.

Comment: @james when you add a column, it's not `not null` by default. If you want to make it `not null`, you'll have to set the column to `not null` for every row *FIRST*. Only then can you make it `not null`.